# How to get subscriber ID of an API in Azure APIM?

Tags: api, azure, subscription, azureportal

I am new to Azure APIM and want to know how to get subscriber ID or anything which can uniquely identifies every subscriber of my API.

Comment: get it where? in apim? or?

Comment: Yes in APIM. Firstly i want to get the value of that attribute which can uniquely identifies each subscriber then I need to append specific attributes in the request based on that subscriber.

Answer (score 4):

You can use APIM management api to get the subscription ID.
In your APIM Instance>Management API 
There you can find the management url and the token to call the endpoint can be generated.

Specifically to get all subscriptions, you can use below endpoint within management url :
`GET: https://{your management url}/subscriptions/?api-version=2018-01-01` Or 
specifically for a product

```
https://{your management url}/products/{productId}/subscriptions?api-version=2018-01-01
```

Below is the Rest API reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription

Or within a APIM policy,
you can find using `context` variables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

```
context.Subscription.Id
```

Comment: the REST API suggested didn't worked for me. Is there any other mean to get the APIM subscription ID?

Comment: That is so strange. I think you doesnt enabled the option of Rest api in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Fo those who are not clear on the answer provided by @VinuBibin, you can get the subscription id during request, inside the policy and inject it into headers as follows:

```
    <set-header name="subscription" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Subscription.Id)</value>
    </set-header>
```